# mod_expires browser caching

Tags: centos, .htaccess, cache

I've enabled the mod_expires module and it is loaded as the `phpinfo()` confirms in the loaded modules section.

All url's point to the file `9123123.js` where `9123123` is the car. However, now I want to leverage browser caching on this file. And added the `<IfModule mod_expires.c>`. But the browser still says:

```
Cached: No
Expires:    Wed, 30 Nov 2016 19:06:10 GMT
```

Contents of the .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?car=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*).js$ index.php?car1&carid=$2 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Did I miss a part?

Comment: "All url's point to the file `9123123.js` where `9123123` is the car." - I assume by this that you mean all documents reference `9123123.js` as an external resource, but what's the bit about "`9123123` is the car"? What does that mean and how does it affect the question? Can you include the full HTTP response headers please. That `Expires` header (assuming that is the response header) looks correct, but mod_expires also sets the `Cache-Control` header, which is the important one for modern browsers. Also, other things like cookies can also _break_ the cache.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue? I am experiencing something very similar doing all the usual steps I would normally do on an Ubuntu setup but can't get them to work on a Centos setup?